# Change Color of Both Side of Wall

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-model, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Dear All,

I can change color of nist_maze_wll_240 with this tag

> ```
>     <material>
>       <ambient>1 0 0 1</ambient>
>       <diffuse>1 0 0 1</diffuse>
>       <specular>0.1 0.1 0.1 1</specular>
>       <emissive>0 0 0 0</emissive>
>     </material>
> ```

but, with this tag just color of one side changed! i want to change color of both side, i tried some tags but those didn't work! also i can rotate the wall but because of fault in saving environment i can't do that. any one can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3687/change-color-of-both-side-of-wall/) by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

looks like the normals are not loaded properly. It's just dark, and if you add a light next to it, it shows the material. I've ticketed an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/789/fix-collada-mesh-normals) to track this

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-07-24**:
Thank you very much, i used the light, but the problem is that light tag don't add to SDF file of environment!